# Dynamic column in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

In my application there are some columns that were given privileges.
If the column is not given the right to access that particular column is not shown.

My code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/5jccbzdy/11/

```
// DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, 'asc']],
        "drawCallback": function (settings){
            var api = this.api();

            // Zero-based index of the column containing names
            var col_name = 0;

            // If ordered by column containing names
            if (api.order()[0][0] === col_name) {
                var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
                var group_last = null;

                api.column(col_name, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (name, index){
                    var group = name;
                    var data = api.row(rows[index]).data();

                    if (group_last !== group) {
                        $(rows[index]).before(
                            '<tr class="group" style="background-color:' + data[4] + '"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                        );

                        group_last = group;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

How to make the above code becomes more dynamic and adjusting the number of columns that are given privileges?

If the number of columns that were given privileges: 5, then:

```
'<tr class="group" style="background-color:' + data[4] + '"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
```

If the number of columns that were given privileges: 3, then:

```
  '<tr class="group" style="background-color:' + data[2] + '"><td colspan="3">' + group + '</td></tr>'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`columns.name`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name) option to define a name for data column containing color.

Then in the row grouping code you can use [`column-selector`](http://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) `color:name` in `api.column("color:name").index()` to get index of that column.

Use the code below:

```
// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "order": [[3, 'asc']],
    "columnDefs": [
        { targets: 3, name: "group" },
        { targets: -1, name: "color" }
     ],
    "drawCallback": function (settings){
        var api = this.api();

        // Zero-based index of the column containing group names
        var col_name = api.column("group:name").index();
        var col_color = api.column("color:name").index();

        // If ordered by column containing names
        if (api.order()[0][0] === col_name) {
            var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
            var group_last = null;

            api.column(col_name, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, index){
                if (group_last !== group){                        
                    var color = api.cell({
                        row: api.row(rows[index]).index(),
                        column: col_color 
                    }).data();

                    $(rows[index]).before(
                        '<tr class="group" style="background-color:' + color + '"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                    );

                    group_last = group;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qtoyunq/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I am still confused. I tried the code above. I change the column "Rendering Engine" to the third column. For example, the column "Engine" is not given the right of access (If not given the right to access that column will be lost). I tried the code like this:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/5qtoyunq/1/).
How can I make that grouped column fixed column "Rendering engine", although the other columns(column "Engine") are not given the right of access (be eliminated)?

Comment: @mosestoh, added more details and updated the example. You can specify indexes of the column containing group and color in `columnDefs` section. Then code in `drawCalback` will use names `group` and `color` to retrieve those indexes instead of having them hardcoded.

Comment: Thank you Gyrocode.com. But I still have difficulty to implement my problem. You try to see here : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/5qtoyunq/1/).  How can I make that grouped column fixed column "Rendering engine", although the other columns(column "Engine") are not given the right of access (be eliminated)? I mean like it.

Comment: @mosestoh, see my updated answer regarding assigning names to columns, also see this http://jsfiddle.net/5qtoyunq/3/